# Random Google Analytics Javascript error

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

We implemented GA code on all of our pages. However, some clients are experiencing javascript errors while using IE11. Specifically, one error indicates "Script Error" and point to the googletagmanager.com URL. Another client sees a random javascript error that says "Object doesn't support property or method 'trim'". As soon as we remove GA codes, these errors go away.

We couldn't pinpoint exactly what causes the javascript error. Does anyone have any experience with these type of errors?

Here is our code:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxx-1"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxx-1');
</script>`
```

Here are the errors:

[image]

[image]
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you paste the actual errors?

Comment: Edited my post to include screenshots, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the global site tagging they implemented the method `trim()` that is not supported on IE11.

You can easily fix your issue by downgrading the code to Universal Analytics.

The global site tagging is handy for most cases (Good comunication between AdW and GA) but it doesn't add that much for Analytics.

You can find the previous snipped [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs)

Comment: Thank you so much, will try the older version!